# Putting devnagari text in xelatex results in question marks instead of text

Tags: xetex, hindi

I want to add a single line of devnagari in my text but cant make it work at all write now. Below is my attempt. 
I get all question marks in the output.

```
% !TEX TS?program = pdflatexmk

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

%for sanskrit
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hindi} %% or other languages

%\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit-Devanagari.ttf}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Devanagari MT}

\linespread{1.5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{introduction}

\section{hindi}

\begin{hindi}
जैसी जिम्मे ऎसाजीस दिनांक विवरण जनित बाटते भारतीय विचरविमर्श बढाता विषय वर्णित पुष्टिकर्ता किया बनाने ज्या
\end{hindi}

text 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

My output looks like below. How can I make it work?
[image]

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-hindi.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/devanagaridigits.sty)
)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [fontsize=12pt].

(./main.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
Chapter 1.
[1] (./main.aux) )
Output written on main.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on main.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Comment: Works fine for me, on macOS (which I imagine you're using too, because of the mention of Devanagari MT), and using either TeX Live or MikTeX — what does the log file say? Are you able to use that font in other applications on your system? And what encoding is your file saved in? (XeTeX assumes UTF-8, but it's possible you're using some buggy editor that saves in some other encoding though I'm not aware of any other that supports Devanagari so probably this is not an issue.)

Comment: yeah it is on macOS, and I am using  `TexShop` for this. I also posted the complete log of compiling the file.

Comment: (1) Can you add `\showoutput` before `\end{document}`, and update the log again? (2) Does the font work if you open say TextEdit (comes with macOS), type some Hindi, and select the same font (Devanagari MT) as the font? (3) If answers to both (1) and (2) are fine, can you upload the actual generated PDF somewhere so that one can take a look?

Comment: Your MWE works for me. Although note that you should use `12pt` not `fontsize=12pt`. And `xelatex` with `fontspec` does not need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.  Your TeX distribution is very old. You are running TeXLive 2015, so perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: @DavidPurton: 2015 was only 4 years ago, and XeTeX has been around and working for a long time. While it's tempting to simply tell everyone to use the latest version of everything, IMO the issue is likely to be something else here rather than the TeX distribution being "very" old.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, you are probably right.

Comment: Works fine for me, too: windows/miktek/xelatex, file in UTF-8 format, font=Noto Serif Devanagari.

Comment: CTAN https://ctan.org/pkg/texshop?lang=en says "TeXShop is a TeX previewer for Mac OS X, written in Cocoa. TeXShop uses pdftex and pdflatex in its default configuration, to conform with Mac OS X’s predilection for PDF. " -- so there is possibly a setting issue.